# How to calculate field values in Views Calc?

Tags: views

In Drupal 7, I have a custom content type containing distance (a decimal field) and time (a date field where only hours, minutes and seconds are entered).

In a view on that custom content type, I would like to show not only distance and time but also speed. (speed = distance / time)

I already tried to create a formula in views calc but:

1. I didn't find a way to get the hour, minute and second values separately from the date field. When I tried to define DATE_FORMAT (%field, '%i'), I got an error mentioning that i is not an allowed value.
2. I tried to work with the value of %field directly (because I found out that the field contains 101HHiiss as value) but I coulnd't define something like %field / 1000000 because then I would get an error mentioning that 00 is not an allowed value.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Sorry, I overread "Views Calc" before I wrote my answer. But maybe it helps you nevertheless.

---

Views maybe isn't the right place to add your custom code to. You might consider writing a very small custom module. Let Views then maybe display full nodes. And in your custom module you might hook into [`hook_node_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7), grab your node's fields, do the calculation and finally add the result as a new field to the the node's content, which then will get rendered automatically:

```
function MY_MODULE_node_view($node) {
    dpm($node); // start with that

    $time = $node->field_time[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    $distance = $node->field_distance[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

    // do your calculations
    // ...

    $speed = $result;

    $node->content['speed'] = array(
        '#prefix' => '<div id="speed">',
        '#markup' => $speed,
        '#suffix' => '</div>'
    );
}
```

When developing your custom module you might find the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module quite helpful. After activating it you can easily check out what's inside a variable and then double click the displayed results for a deeper insight. So you might start by calling `dpm($node)` right inside `hook_node_view()`.